# Permission denied even though I have full access

Tags: permissions

I am trying to use execute my mira file in `/mnt/c/Miranda/mira-2042-i686-Linux/usr/bin`

When I do 
`ls -l` I see that my user has permission level `-rwxrwxrwx 1 user user 598852 sep 11 2008 mira`

However, when I try to execute the file I still get an permission error.

Could someone tell me what the issue is?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Hi! Can you please show us exactly how you are trying to execute that file?

Comment: What command did you use to mount the drive? Regardless of whether the file has executable permission, you need to *mount* the drive with executable permission. Also, is this drive ntfs, vfat, or something else?

Comment: To gain sufficient info to solveyour problem, please run my `pathlld` script, available from https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld.git